# Array to Dictionary Output Python

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following list after querying my DB which I'd like to turn into a dictionary:

```
[{date: date_value1.1, rate: rate_value1.1, source: source_name1},
{date: date_value1.2, rate: rate_value1.2, source: source_name1},
{date: date_value2.1, rate: rate_value2.1, source: source_name2},
{date: date_value2.2, rate: rate_value2.2, source: source_name2},
{date: date_valuenx, rate: rate_valuex, source: source_namex}, ...]
```

The dictionary should follow the following format:

```
{
  source_name1:
    [
      {date: date_value1.1, rate: rate_value1.1}
      {date: date_value1.2, rate: rate_value1.2}
    ],
  source_name2:
    [
      {date: date_value2.1, rate: rate_value2.1}
      {date: date_value2.2, rate: rate_value2.2}
    ],
}
```

I have tried a lot of different code variations, but could not get it to work. What would be the most efficient way to transform the data into the required format?

*(This format is the response the client will receive after calling my API. If you have suggestions for better formatting of this response I am also open to suggestions!)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `defaultdict` and simply append each result to our output list.

```
from collections import defaultdict

output = defaultdict(list)

data = [{'date': 'date_value1.1', 'rate': 'rate_value1.1', 'source': 'source_name1'}, {'date': 'date_value1.2', 'rate': 'rate_value1.2', 'source': 'source_name1'}, {'date': 'date_value2.1', 'rate': 'rate_value2.1', 'source': 'source_name2'}, {'date': 'date_value2.2', 'rate': 'rate_value2.2', 'source': 'source_name2'}, {'date': 'date_valuenx', 'rate': 'rate_valuex', 'source': 'source_namex'}]

for row in data:
    output[row['source']].append({k: v for k, v in row.items() if k != 'source'})

dict(output)
#{'source_name1': [{'date': 'date_value1.1', 'rate': 'rate_value1.1'}, {'date': 'date_value1.2', 'rate': 'rate_value1.2'}], 'source_name2': [{'date': 'date_value2.1', 'rate': 'rate_value2.1'}, {'date': 'date_value2.2', 'rate': 'rate_value2.2'}], 'source_namex': [{'date': 'date_valuenx', 'rate': 'rate_valuex'}]}
```

---

```
import pprint

pprint.pprint(dict(output))

{'source_name1': [{'date': 'date_value1.1', 'rate': 'rate_value1.1'},
                  {'date': 'date_value1.2', 'rate': 'rate_value1.2'}],
 'source_name2': [{'date': 'date_value2.1', 'rate': 'rate_value2.1'},
                  {'date': 'date_value2.2', 'rate': 'rate_value2.2'}],
 'source_namex': [{'date': 'date_valuenx', 'rate': 'rate_valuex'}]}
```

Comment: Match his expected output with yours first.

Comment: @edusanketdk The output matches for his example.

Comment: This achieved exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
d = [{"date":" date_value1.1", "rate": "rate_value1.1", "source": "source_name1"},
{"date": "date_value1.2", "rate": "rate_value1.2", "source": "source_name1"},
{"date": "date_value2.1", "rate": "rate_value2.1", "source": "source_name2"},]
    
d1 = {}
for ele in d:
    key = ele.pop('source')
    d1[key] = d1.get(key, list())
    d1[key].append(ele)

print(d1)
```

output is:

```
{'source_name1': [{'date': ' date_value1.1', 'rate': 'rate_value1.1'}, {'date': 'date_value1.2', 'rate': 'rate_value1.2'}], 'source_name2': [{'date': 'date_value2.1', 'rate': 'rate_value2.1'}]}
```

Comment: Does not match with what OP needs.

Comment: Or you could also do, ``d1.setdefault(ele.pop('source'), []).append(ele)``